# Selector to Hyperlink TextView

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, selector

I have a `TextView` whose click triggers the browser to open a url.How to apply selector to the `TextView`. I tried `android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"` which is working for all other `TextViews`.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtWebsite"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
android:textSize="@dimen/web_textsize"
android:textStyle="normal" />
```

I tried `android:textColorLink="@drawable/text_selector"` also which isn't working either.

Comment: what you actually want , do you want to change the color of the textview after clicking on it.?

Comment: what exactly your trying to achieve can you explain in simple words ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Workaround:

I implemented by my way and it's working fine.

```
    textview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textview.setClickable(true);
    String mystring=new String("https://www.google.com");
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(mystring);

    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mystring.length(), 0);
    textview.setText(content);

    textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

and `XML textView`

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="http://www.google.com"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selector"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and `res/color/selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#7fa87f" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:color="#ff33b5" android:state_focused="true" />
<!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#061476" />
<!-- default -->
</selector>
```

### OutPut: With Hover

[image: With Hover]

### OutPut: Without Hover

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set clickable TextView Programatically by code.

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Click here to learn more");
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And in XML add below two lines:

```
            android:autoLink="web"                
            android:linksClickable="true"
```

Hope it will help you.